# 2D Collision Detection Problem

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

while making my game called "Journeys of Nemo the Fish" i stumbled upon a collision detection problem. Please, help me to solve it.

The problem is: the program runs only the first if statement adjusting the coordinates of the player without taking in consideration what type of collision occurred.

Here is my code:

```
    short int py = player.getPosition().y;
    short int px = player.getPosition().x;
    short int pw = player.getGlobalBounds().width;
    short int ph = player.getGlobalBounds().height;

    for (int i = 0; i < block.size(); i++) {
        short int by = block[i].getPosition().y;
        short int bx = block[i].getPosition().x;
        short int bw = block[i].getGlobalBounds().width;
        short int bh = block[i].getGlobalBounds().height;

        if (player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(block[i].getGlobalBounds())) {
             // UP and DOWN
             if (px+pw > bx && px < bx+bw) {
                 if (py < by+bh && py > by) {
                     py = by + bh;
                 } else if (py+ph > by && py < by) {
                     py = by - ph;
                 }
             }

             break;
         }

          if (player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(block[i].getGlobalBounds())) {
             //LEFT and RIGHT
             if (py+ph > by && py < by+bh) {
                 if (px < bx+bw && px+pw > bx+bh) {
                     px = bx + bw;
                 } else if (px+pw > bx && px < bx) {
                     px = bx - pw;
                 }
             }

             break;
         }
     }
```

Here is a link to the video: [Journeys of Nemo the Fish.](https://vk.com/videos288972144?z=video288972144_456239022%2Fpl_288972144_-2)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED

When a collision occurs

```
if (px+pw > bx && px < bx+bw) {
```

Will be true in the two collision types. There is no way to know wich type of collision is. I would create a new variable called typeOfMovement to know wether fish is moving up/down or left/right

```
short int py = player.getPosition().y;
short int px = player.getPosition().x;
short int pw = player.getGlobalBounds().width;
short int ph = player.getGlobalBounds().height;

for (int i = 0; i < block.size(); i++) {
    short int by = block[i].getPosition().y;
    short int bx = block[i].getPosition().x;
    short int bw = block[i].getGlobalBounds().width;
    short int bh = block[i].getGlobalBounds().height;

    if (player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(block[i].getGlobalBounds())) {
         // left/right
         if (typeOfMovement == 0) {
             if (py < by+bh && py > by) {
                 py = by + bh;
             } else if (py+ph > by && py < by) {
                 py = by - ph;
             }
         }
         // Up/Down
        else if (typeOfMovement == 1) {
             if (px < bx+bw && px+pw > bx+bh) {
                 px = bx + bw;
             } else if (px+pw > bx && px < bx) {
                 px = bx - pw;
             }
         }

     }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this out, but it didn't really changed the problem. Somehow, the first IF statement is run in both cases.